# Thunderlord's Decree damage applies before of after AA/ability?

Tags: league-of-legends

Lets say I am playing veigar, the ultimate works as an execute.
If my ultimate is the ability that triggers the thunderlord. What applies first?the ultimate damage or thunderlords?
If thunderlords applies first, then I get more damage on my ultimate. 
I want to know if it makes any difference in calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thunderlord's Decree works based on taking damage from abilities and auto attacks. If no damage is taken, no stacks of Thunderlord's is applied. The only exception to this rule is for damage over time abilities, such as Twitch/Cassiopeia/Teemo/Singed poison, Fiddlestick's W (drain), or Swain's E (torment).

This means ability/auto attack damage must happen before the full proc occurs. So when playing Veigar, when using his ult, Thunderlords happens after the ult hits and thus does not increase the raw ult damage.

Comment: Something I'd like to add: While the damage of damage over time effects doesn't add a stack to Thunderlords, the triggering spell often does (Fiddle W, Cassio Q). So for example if you auto attack twice and drain something after with Fiddle, TL will proc, even though a drain alone won't trigger it.

Comment: @Jutschge Yes that's because it's coded not to apply the mark if it's with the same spell. However Cass's repeated Es would proc it. Also this answer really does't add anything that I hadn't said before..  Not that I'd usually comment this, but If I'm not mistaken that's what you commented on a poor guy's answers a while back

Comment: @Oak I'm assuming that last comment was directed at me - I only comment "doesn't really add anything new" to newly posted answers on old questions where other questions have already said the same thing, often months or years before the new post. In this case, we both posted answers at almost the exact same time (I think we were a couple seconds off). And finally, my answer does include a little extra info that your doesn't - I gave some examples of the exclusions which only count for a single stack of TL.

Answer (score 1):

**From the [wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Thunderlord%27s_Decree):**

> Hitting an enemy champion with an ability (ability damage) or basic attack (on-hit) marks them with Thunderlord's Decree for 3 seconds.

That means that Thunderlords' damage will be applied as soon as the third mark is applied.

Since the mark is applied after ability damage or on-hit damage, then in your scenario, Veigar's ultimate will be the third mark and Thunderlords will damage after the ultimate damage.